# Trigger click events while button is pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive that moves an element to the right. In each click, the item is moved to the right, but I would like that the element moves as long I am keeping the button pressed.

```
.directive("car", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        link:function(scope,element,attrs,controller){
            var left=0;
            var car = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.car'));
            var move = function(e){
                left+=10;
                car[0].style.left = left+"px";
            };
            element.on("click", move);
        }
    };
})
```

So how can I detect when the button is being pressed each half second and recall the `move` function again? Is it possible to have a smooth movement?

There is a interactive demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/2m8vD/

I cannot use jQuery for this, but I may use AngularJS modules like ngTouch or whatever.

Comment: Pseudocode suggestion: Why not set a variable when the button is pressed, clear it when the button is no longer pressed. You would then just move the car in increments as long as that variable is true.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/BPGNWWxSr6M/5Vj6GGY-utQJ).

Comment: +1 for the entertaining demo:)

Comment: I tend to avoid triggering or simulating events as a result of a different event — it can quickly get really ugly. I prefer re-using a method or related methods based on the different events, as Aaronias has done, and I've voted for that answer.

Comment: Does the correct answer require the car to move smoothly?

Comment: It would be great... But maybe I will let that for other question.

Comment: @StephenP that is the approach I took in the example provided, repeating the call to the "move" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aaronias put me in the right track, kudos to him.

I managed to achieve smooth movement when holding the button and cancellable when the mouse moves out. The key is remove the CSS transition, start an interval doing small steps and cancel that interval on mouseout or mouseup.

```
var move = function(e){
    if(interval)
        return;

    step(e);
    mustStop = false;

    interval = $interval(function(){
        step(e);
        if(mustStop){
            $interval.cancel(interval);
            mustStop = false;
            interval = null;
        }
    }, 10);
};

var stop = function(){ mustStop= true;};

right.on("mousedown", move)
    .on("mouseup", stop)
    .on("mouseout", stop);

left.on("mousedown", move)
    .on("mouseup", stop)
    .on("mouseout", stop);
```

This is the version of the example where it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/2m8vD/22/

Answer (score 3):

I did a simple mockup of a way to solve you're issue using mouseup and mousedown events with the $timeout service.

```
.directive("car", function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        link:function(scope,element,attrs,controller){
            var left=0;
            var car = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.car'));
            var timeout;
            var moveOnce= function() {
                left+=10;
                car[0].style.left = left+"px";
            };
            var move = function(e){
                $timeout.cancel(timeout);
                timeout = $timeout(function(){
                    moveALittle();
                    move();
                }, 250);
            };
            var stop = function(e){
                $timeout.cancel(timeout);
            };
            element.on("click", moveOnce);
            element.on("mousedown", move);
            element.on("mouseup", stop);

            element.on("$destroy",function(){
                element.off("click",moveOnce);
                element.off("mousedown", move);
                element.off("mouseup", stop);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Here is an updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2m8vD/12/

You should be able to easily update the the timeout delay and pixel movement to get the movement to be as smooth as you like.

As an alternative to using the mouseup and mousedown events you can easily enough use the angular directives ng-mouseup and ng-mousedown events bound directly to the button element.

```
<button ng-mousedown="move" ng-mouseup="stop">Move</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

Added moveOnce() function to allow for a single click.

Comment: nice, but it does not move if you just click

Comment: Updated to allow for a single click.

Comment: looking good. Another issue, if you click inside but release out of the control (mouseup is not captured by that directive) the car does not stop